# What's the best way to do listing with searching, sorting and pagination with redis and nodejs?

Tags: redis, amazon-elasticache, node-redis, redis-cluster

I have a list of contacts where I am fetching millions of data and showing in a list with pagination, keyword search and column sorting option. I want to implement redis over here to serve the result faster.

My question is what's the best way to use redis in the above mentioned scenario? Also if redis does not fit over here then suggest me some alternative solution which can be fit over here to server my purpose. I am working in nodejs serverless stack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[RediSearch module](https://oss.redis.com/redisjson/) seems like the perfect fit here.

```
FT.SEARCH users "@last_name:jones" SORTBY first_name DESC LIMIT 0 10
```

Here you are filtering on the last_name, sorting by the first_name and paginating, displaying 10 results, starting from the first one (zero-based)

Comment: Consider using TAG fields for first_name and last_name instead of TEXT fields.